# Map of H-spaces inducing zero on homologies

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

If a map of $H$-spaces $f:X\rightarrow Y$ induces zero on the homology groups at dimensions greater than zero does it necessarily induce zero map on the homotopy groups? It is definitely true for $\pi_1$ as it is Abelian and can be identified with the first homology. The statement is also true rationally since rational homotopy can be identified with primitives of the rational homology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $\pi^k$ denote the kth cohomotopy group, the contravariant functor that measures homotopy classes of maps into the k-sphere. Given a map $[f]:S^n \rightarrow S^k$ we get a natural transformation $\pi^n \rightarrow \pi^k$ (given by postcomposition). Let $\eta$ denote the nontrivial element of $\pi_7(S^3)= \mathbb{Z}_2$. This gives a natural transformation $\pi^7 \rightarrow \pi^3$ that cannot be the 0 natural transformation by Yoneda's lemma. This means there is some map $[g]: S^m \rightarrow S^7$ such that $[\eta \circ g]: S^m \rightarrow S^3$ is not trivial.

We know $[g] \in \pi_m(S^7)$, so we can say that $\eta_*:\pi_m(S^7) \rightarrow \pi_m(S^3)$ is nonzero. Obviously, $\eta$ induces 0 maps on homology. As well, both $S^3$ and $S^7$ are H-spaces.

Comment: To be more concrete, $m=7$ and $g$ is the identity map.

Comment: Thanks,  a very beautiful counterexample. What do you think happens if I replace the condition that induce zero on homotopy groups by the image of the map induced on the homotopy groups are finitely generated? (In order to find a counter example one needs to work with infinite CW complexes.). My original problem was something like this if the image of the induced map on the homologies are finitely generated then the image of the induced map on the homotopy groups are also finitely generated. I hoped to use Serre mod $C$ to reduce it to the problem above.

Comment: I don't really know how to approach it. If I were trying to find a counterexample, I would probably start with messing around with Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, but I don't know much about their homology.